# WPF Data Binding to bool Not Working

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to bind the `IsEnabled` property of a set of `ListBoxItem`s to a `bool` property value that resides in the `DataContext`. I have followed several tutorials to get to where I am however I am still not having any luck. In my XAML I have defined a `setter` within a `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` as follows:

```
<ListBox Name="Requests">
     <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
               <Setter Property="IsEnabled" 
                       Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
```

The `bool` property value resides in a class set as the `DataContext` as such:

```
public class dcSystemRequests : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _IsEnabled;
        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get 
            {
                return _IsEnabled; 
            }
            set 
            {
                if (_IsEnabled != value)
                {
                    _IsEnabled = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyChanged)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyChanged));
            }
        }
```

Now when I modify the property I am not seeing the value reflected in the UI as expected; the property value is being changed in the code like this:

```
((dcSystemRequests)DataContext).IsEnabled = !((dcSystemRequests)DataContext).IsEnabled;
```

Since this is proprietary software I only included what I think is necessary to understand the issue but will happily provide more if needed. Any advice or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: doesn't make sense to me. You have only 1 bool, and need to toggle many items? independently? either make many bools or toggle the `ListBox.IsEnabled` instead.

Comment: I chose this route because disabling the ListBox disables the scroll-bar as well. I need the scroll-bar enabled on the ListBox. Also - I have an undefined number of entries so having multiple bools is not an option.

Comment: You should bind to the isenabled property from within your listbox datatemplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the IsEnabled property is part of the `ListBox`'s DataContext, then you need to use a [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) binding:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" 
            Value="{Binding DataContext.IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}"/>
</Style>
```

The `DataContext` of the `ListBoxItem`s is each corresponding Data Item.

See [ItemsControl](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ItemContainerStyle` has not the same `DataContext` as your `ListBox`, but the data of the ListBox's items. Therefore binding to the `IsEnabled` property makes no sense if you do not set the binding Source to the `ListBoxItem`'s parent.

Comment: This is the right answer, however HighCore responded a minute sooner. Thanks for the assistance!